# Выражение "До которого времени"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Корректно ли звучит вопрос "До которого времени?"?

(Следует ли ставить два вопросительных знака в этом предложении?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос звучит *некорректно*, по крайней мере, для неопределённого контекста (в котором ранее не назывались какие-либо варианты *сроков* и т. п.). Дело в том, что "который" предполагает *выбор* из ограниченного, дискретного числа альтернатив. Именно такая дискретность делает возможым вопрос "*до **которого** часа*?" (условно подразумеваются имеющиеся в сутках часы, число которых конечно). В общем случае правильнее спросить: "*до **какого** времени* (напр. вы откладываете это решение)?"

Answer (score 4):

Ответ на второй вопрос.

Повторять вопросительный знак не следует.

[**О сочетаниях знаков препинания**](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/165-oszp)

> **Примечание 1**. Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит знак вопросительный, или восклицательный, или многоточие, то те же самые знаки **не повторяются** после кавычек; неодинаковые же знаки, если они требуются в силу характера соответствующих частей текста, могут ставиться перед закрывающими кавычками и после них, например:

*Читали ли вы роман Чернышевского «Что делать?»*

Но:

*Драматический кружок готовит к постановке пьесу «В бой!».*