# Какой это принцип орфографии?

Tags: орфография, общие-вопросы

Проверяем безударную гласную в окончании прилагательного:

***В син…м небе*** (каком?) – окончание **ОМ**, после мягкого согласного пишем **ЕМ**.

**Почему пишется ЕМ?** Какой  это принцип орфографии? Морфологический?

Но здесь нет единообразного написания морфем: в проверочном слове буква О, а  в заданном слове – буква Е.

Как такая ситуация **объясняется в школе** (в младших и старших классах)?

Comment: Подскажите, а что с запятыми перед ИЛИ в ответе Александра? Там как бы вообще не должно их быть, одну ещё можно поставить, но не две. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460610

Comment: А что с ними не так; Там три однородных члена, союз ИЛИ повторяется со второго члена. Поэтому это перечисление, все запятые ставятся.

Comment: Пример: *сегодня и завтра, и послезавтра => сегодня или завтра, или послезавтра*.

Comment: Сегодня, или завтра, или послезавтра. Такой вариант тоже возможен, причем он выглядит естественнее, чем ваш.

Comment: Если стоит:  или (1) знак вопросительный, или (2) знак восклицательный, или (3) многоточие...  Обычное перечисление.

Comment: Если соответствовать научному стилю изложения, то запятых вообще быть не должно: *стоит {знак {вопросительный или восклицательный} или многоточие}*.

Comment: @oleedd   Розенталь, [Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#).   Если однородных членов предложения более двух, а союз повторяется перед каждым из них, кроме первого, то запятая ставится между всеми однородными членами: ... *А вокруг были дым, и бой, и смерть* (М. Г.); *Отрывистый и ломаный звук метался, и прыгал, и бежал куда-то в сторону от других* (Андр.)...

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Это уже видел. Предыдущий комментарий прочитайте.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю наверняка, как сейчас, но думаю, что как и раньше, такие вещи в школе не объясняют за отсутствием необходимости. Тут для практических надобностей достаточно запомнить, что без ударения ЕМ, а не ИМ. То есть фонетический принцип тут не работает.

А работающий принцип, конечно, морфологический. "Ом" и "Ем" - тут варианты одной морфемы, подверженной позиционному чередованию.
Исторический переход О<Е (иногда и в обратную сторону) никак не подрывает основ морфологии. Есть еще более впечатляющие примеры, где чередование не позиционное, а историческое: единый-один<един, олень<елень, осень<есень.

Comment: @ЕгорСальков А вы вопрос прочитали? *В син…м небе (каком?) – окончание ОМ, после мягкого согласного пишем ЕМ."* Или у вас сомнения в моей формулировке? Если второе, то прошу конкретнее, что именно вам не нравится.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.

Answer (score 0):

1. «Основным принципом русской орфографии является **морфологический.** Он определяет такое письмо, при котором сохраняется **единообразное написание морфем** (приставок, суффиксов, окончаний) независимо от их звучания в том или ином случае».
2. Но никто не говорит о том, что у морфем может быть два или несколько **алломорфов,** имеющих постоянный фонемный состав.

В данном случае  у морфемы ОМ/ЕМ  два алломорфа, которые обозначаются буквами на письме,  в то время как в устной речи (в безударной позиции) реализуется морф ИМ и др.

Такое письмо **сложно назвать единообразным** в прямом смысле этого слова (там как бы **два образа,** а  не один).

3. **Это недоступно** пониманию наших школьников?  Но, может быть, раньше так и было, а теперь они поумнели?  В химии, например, электронные облака они изучают  в базовой программе, а с родным языком не могут разобраться?  Или  педагоги не  могут составить  соответствующую методику обучения?
4. А если это **ненужные для практики знания**, то и про орфографические принципы лучше бы забыть, чем изучать их формально.